# How to find the highest value with winner take all

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

How can I implement K-winner take all easily in python?

I have an array with different values: `[0, 8, 0.3, 0.2, ...]`

I want that `k` elements with the highest values are set to `1` the others to `0`

for `k=0.3`, if there are 100 values, at the end 30 (with the highest values) are 1 all the other are 0

Comment: I would suggest you try to write some code.

Comment: @user3012759 That's not helpful. While the problem can be frustratingly easy for you, and the question write-up is not the best ever, it's not a bad question at all

Comment: @goncalopp, I think the problem is not a bad problem, but the question is quite bad... zero effort, no code, just using SO as code writing service which it is not right?

Comment: Edoardo, you might find that taking more time and care while writing your question will lead to better reception (and more answers)

Answer (score 2):

Let `l` be the original list ("array")

For `k==1/len(l)` (only one maximum number), this is easy.

The key realization is that the algorithm can be decomposed in three parts:

- finding the maximum element
- creating a new list that has all elements set to `0`
- setting the correct element to `1` (in the new list)

These steps are quite easy to perform individually. If you need help on any of these, feel free to ask another question (make sure to check if someone asked it before).

---

Writing a **efficient** algorithm for an arbitrary `k` is more complex, but I'll assume you value simplicity over performance (since you're writing this in python)

- let `j` be `len(l)*k` (the number of elements whose maximum you want)
- Sort the list in decreasing order
- Let `threshold` be the value of the `j`th element in the sorted list. This is the index of the minimum element you want to set to `1`.
- create a new list that has all elements set to 0
- set all elements `>= threshold` to 1 (in the new list)

---

A slightly more complex but pythonic implementation:

```
#-----input
l=[1,6,2,5,3,4]
k=0.5
#---------
j= int(len(l)*k)
threshold= sorted(l)[j]
result= [int(x>=threshold) for x in l]
```

output: `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1,2,44,5,100]
>>> new_list = []
>>> max(a)
100
>>> for values in a:
...     if values < 100:
...             values = 0
...             new_list.append(values)
...     else:
...             values = 1
...             new_list.append(values)
... 
>>> print new_list
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: note that this only answers the case where `k==1/len(a)`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
a=[4, 3, 9, 6, 8, 7, 10, 5, 2, 1] 
k=0.3
cutoff=int(k*len(a) )
b=zip( a, range(len(a)) )
c=zip( sorted(b,reverse=True), range(len(b)) )
d=map( lambda r: (r[0][1],1) if r[1]<cutoff else (r[0][1],0),  c )
[ i[1] for i in sorted(d) ]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

For ease of comparison, the input repeated:

```
[4, 3, 9, 6, 8, 7, 10, 5, 2, 1]
```

I could have written the code more dense, but like this you can inspect variable a,b,c and d.

Comment: `zip( a, range(len(a)) )` could just be `enumerate(a)`, if you swap the order. But, in general, carrying the indexes in tuples makes this more complex than it needs to be

Comment: True, this is much more convoluted then it should be, and furthermore it doesn't take 'draws' into account (ie. equal values round the cutoff point).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way that you can implement `K-winner-take-all` function in deep learning frameworks:

```
sparse_factor = 0.3
x = torch.randn([1, 10])

k = int(sparse_factor * x.shape[1])
topval = x.topk(k, dim=1)[0][:, -1]
topval = topval.expand(x.shape[1], x.shape[0]).permute(1, 0)
comp = (x >= topval).to(x)
print(comp * x)
```

> tensor([[-0.0000, -0.0000, 0.0000, -0.0000, 1.0534, 0.0000, 1.1854,
>   0.9829, -0.0000,
>            0.0000]])